# How to get revel modal in foundation to work properly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation

I am trying to use Foundation to get the reveal modal to work. When I click on the link below, nothing happens. When I load the page, the content in the modal is displayed, but it looks very strange.

```
<!doctype html>
    <html class="no-js" lang="en" dir="ltr">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Foundation for Sites</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
      </head>
      <body>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="large-12 columns">
            <h1>Welcome to Foundation</h1>
            <a href="#" data-reveal-id="myModal">Click Me For A Modal</a>

                <div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal" data-reveal aria-labelledby="modalTitle" aria-hidden="true" role="dialog">
                  <h2 id="modalTitle">Awesome. I have it.</h2>
                  <p class="lead">Your couch.  It is mine.</p>
                  <p>I'm a cool paragraph that lives inside of an even cooler modal. Wins!</p>
                  <a class="close-reveal-modal" aria-label="Close">&#215;</a>
                </div>


          </div>
        </div>


        <script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/vendor/what-input.js"></script>
        <script src="js/vendor/foundation.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>

        <script>
            $('#myModal').foundation('open')
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using [Foundation 6](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/reveal.html) examples?

Instead of `data-reveal-id`, use `data-open` or `data-toggle` to target your reveal:

```
<a href="#" data-open="myModal">Click Me For A Modal</a>
<a href="#" data-toggle="myModal">Click Me For A Modal</a>
```

Comment: Data-open opens the modal but it looks very strange now...I'll include a picture above.

Comment: Do you have any custom styles applied? If you use only foundation stylesheets, does it still look the same?